# iOS IAP subscription Time Bomb

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase, trialware

Basically I want to create a paid application on the iTunes Store [for example $1.99]... Now I want that $1.99 to allow the user to use the app for 12 months. Then in order to continue to use the application the user will have to subscribe to an renewable IAP every year after that.

I was thinking of using a "time-bomb" that would track 365 days from when the user created their account.

Initially I didn't believe this model was possible but I read that WhatsApp have now adopted a similar strategy so I wanted to double check before I implemented it.

Can anyone confirm, deny or shred any light on this situation?

Comment: "Can anyone confirm, deny or shred any light on this situation?" - Apple?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple's app store policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure there is no built-in way to make the user rebuy the app from iTunes. To achieve something like the WhatsApp yourself, I do not know how they specifically have it set up, you will need to make your app account based. Meaning anyone can download your app, but they will have to go through your service, to create an account that they paid for, that will let them use your app. Sort of like what the Apple Developer Center does, you buy a year to use the service, and at the end of the year, the service is still there, but you will have to repay to continue to use it.

There is many ways to do this, you can build and program your own server (Hard for beginners) or use a pre-made service, like [Parse.com](http://Parse.com) (Very easy for beginners). The reason I named [Parse.com](http://Parse.com), because not only it allows you to make your app fully cloud based with or with out accounts or that it is cross-platformed through many of the popular OSs, but because it is easy to use and they have a pre-made customizable account class built in. You can then use Apple's In-app Purchases to renew the account from [Parse.com](http://Parse.com). For example, have the account contain a variable that holds how many days are left on the account, and if you buy more days from In-app Purchases, it will add more days, and if it has no more days, that account will not be able to use the features of the app, except to buy more days through In-app Purchases.

I hoped I directed you in a better direction.

Comment: Hi @RandomAwesomeGuy thats a really good answer. I am familiar with parse.com and have used it in previous apps. That confirms most of my assumptions, 

However I was under the impression there was a rule in the Developer Guidelines which basically said [and this is from memory] that you can't take away existing functionality. So if the user could use it fine for a year and then can't open the app that would be grounds for rejection.. Did I imagine this or am I misinterpreting its meaning?

Comment: After I just skinned the approval guidelines, https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html, the only thing that I saw that was relevant, is that you cannot add features through third party mechanics, other than the app store, so if you use In-app Purchases, I think you would be fine. I also could of missed something else in the guidelines, so you should give it a reread. And finally, to tell you the truth, how is what you are planning to do, any different than the Netflix app or Amazon Prime app?

Comment: In my example above, I think it is a very bad idea to prevent the app from opening, this is on the grounds for rejection. But a workaround, that I said above, is that you can still open the app at anytime, but the only thing you can do when you have no more days on your account, is buy In-app purchases that will allow the account you have logged in to continue to use the "pro" features. @thesimpsons666